# Setting up a db connection using variables from another file

Tags: php, scope

I am attempting to set up a db connection for a mysqli_connect statement $dbc. I had it working in my script with the following:

```
DEFINE ('DB_USER','myName';
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD','somePass123';
DEFINE ('DB_HOST','localhost';
DEFINE ('DB_NAME','sitename';


// make the db connection
    $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME)
    OR die ('Could not connect to mysql: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
```

I then posted a question on SO about security and best practice and was advised that if the connection variables (password, host, dbname, user) exist elsewhere in a separate database configuration file, that I should call the variables for the connection from there.

Here is the relevant snippet from the file in config/database/php

```
$config['default'] = array(
    'benchmark' => TRUE,
    'persistent' => FALSE,
    'connection' => array(
        'type' => 'mysqli',
        'user' => 'myName',
        'pass' => 'somepass123',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => FALSE,
        'socket' => FALSE,
        'database' => 'sitename',
    ),
    'character_set' => 'utf8',
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'object' => TRUE,
    'cache' => FALSE,
    'escape' => TRUE
);
```

So I then tried this:

```
DEFINE ('DB_USER','$config['default']['connection']['user'])';
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD',$config['default']['connection']['pass']);
DEFINE ('DB_HOST',$config['default']['connection']['host']);
DEFINE ('DB_NAME',$config['default']['connection']['database']);


// make the db connection
    $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME)
    OR die ('Could not connect to mysql: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
```

Which produced the following error when I tried to load the page:
"Undefined variable: config"

I then tried this:

```
 $dbc = @mysqli_connect(
    $config['default']['connection']['host'],
    $config['default']['connection']['user'],
    $config['default']['connection']['pass'],
    $config['default']['connection']['database'])

    OR die ('Could not connect to mysql: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

// Set the encoding
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');

// set the query variable
$query = "SELECT MAX(rating_date) 
          AS last_date
          FROM rating
          WHERE incident_id = $incident_id;";

//connect and run the query
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

 echo $result->fetch_object()->last_date;

?>
```

Which then produced the following error:
"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in..."

I'm not 100% sure what this is telling me. Yesterday I learned that one cannot echo a SQL query in php directly because it's an object so I cut n pasted the part "echo $result->fetch_object()->last_date;" which worked.

It seems that now that I am trying to draw upon the variables from config, rather than just define them in the function, I am unable to connect perhaps due to a scope issue?

The file with the $dbc connection is in a folder themes/myname/views/reports/detail.php

The file with the database configuration details array is in application/config/database.php

It looks like an issue of variable scope?

What would be the best practice here in making my $dbc variable? How do I call the variables from database.php when it exists in a different directory than the file where I'm calling it? Must I include() the whole file?

Comment: Did you include the config file?

Comment: why define constants based on variables? That's like hauling a load of horses in a horse-drawn wagon... If you're going to use variables to store configuration data, then just use those variables directly.

Comment: @Mathlight no. Should I (I'm sorry if this sounds silly you can probably guess my level of experience with PHP)

Comment: @MarcB, Only because this script was a slightly hacked page on a PHP textbook - that's where I am in my PHP development :-)

Comment: @DougFirr, yes. You should include / require it before using the variable's. It's then if you insert the data of that file in your script, so that you have full access to the variables and functions in that file. [link to php.net require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something *sane* like:

```
$dbc = @mysqli_connect(
  $config['default']['connection']['host'],
  $config['default']['connection']['user'],
  $config['default']['connection']['pass'],
  $config['default']['connection']['database'])
OR die ('Could not connect to mysql: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
```

You don't gain anything by using `define()`, you're only trying to avoid putting the raw strings with your username and password into the `mysqli_connect()` call in case an error occurs and that line gets sent to the client in an error message/stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

Constants are global and you don't need to set them as global to retrieve them from the memory but variables are not, if you are calling the variable `$config` from inside a function you have two ways to call it:

1. Set the variable to be global at the first beginning of your function that you are calling this variable from `global $config;`

OR

1. Call the variable using the `$GLOBALS` variable `$config = $GLOBALS['config'];`