# Is it possible to set up a PDO DB connection using variables defined in another file? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So, I have a config.php file with

```
define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'database_user');
define('DB_PASS', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name');
```

**When I am defining my PDO connection, am I able to use this?**

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=DB_HOST;dbname=DB_NAME;charset=utf8", "DB_USER", "DB_PASS");
```

I saw this question: [Setting up a db connection using variables from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342205/setting-up-a-db-connection-using-variables-from-another-file) which is similar, but it's using mysqli_connection, and I'm not sure how different that is from PDO, so I'm not certain if the answer solves my question.

**If I'm not able to use the defined variables from my config.php file, should I define them locally in my file using**:

```
$db_host = DB_HOST;
$db_user = DB_USER;
```

and so on...

**Or am I using the PDO connection with the config.php defined variables incorrectly? If so, how should I be doing it?**

The error I'm receiving when I try to run my webpage says that it cannot connect to the database host (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.) which I assume my PDO connection defined variables are the culprit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use them as constants, but including them in a string like that will make it think they're strings, not constants. You can modify your connection like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={DB_HOST};dbname={DB_NAME};charset=utf8", DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

OR

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";charset=utf8", DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.

Comment: This answers my question, but I now have another problem.  I'll mark your answer though, since it helped me greatly. :)

Comment: Ah! So I tried using {DB_HOST} and {DB_NAME} and would receive an error code 2002 (Message: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '%s' (%d)).  So I tried using the string literals to make sure it wasn't an actual connection issue -- that worked.  So I tried your second option, concatenating the constants into the connection definition, and that worked!